# Is it possible to create a site collection with Publishing site with workflow template in Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Is it possible to create a site collection with Publishing site with workflow template in SharePoint 2010? can we do this from UI i.e via central admin not via code?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that can be done via Central Admin. It is in the Publishing section as Publishing Portal. It should come with approval workflow turned on already for the Pages library.